# Are quantum batteries actually possible and even if they are possible doesn't they break law of conservation of energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy-conservation, batteries

I don't know even the infinitesimal amount of this concept. But I at least know about law of conservation of energy and have the simple intuition that I can not do any magic to miracleously get as much as energy as I want.

Comment: Can you explain what makes you think that someone claims that a quantum battery can get as much energy as they want? My impression is that quantum batteries could be neat since they dont lose charge over time.

Comment: What's the definition of a quantum battery?

Answer (score 1):

Since batteries are moving electrons and electrons have a quantized amount of mass, all batteries are quantum batteries.